# Maven pom.xml with more than one jar with version

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <name>SomeProject</name>

    <groupId>com.test.te</groupId>
    <artifactId>testjar</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
    ....
    ....
    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.conf</include>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>drive</id>
                        <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <finalName>driver</finalName>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com/test/te/p1/*.java<include>
                                    <include>com/test/te/p1/*.class</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is how I am executing this

```
mvn clean install
```

Here is the build output's last few lines.

```
[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/mycp/workspace/SomeProject/target/testjar-1.1.6.jar
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing /home/mycp/workspace/SomeProject/target/testjar-1.1.6.jar to /home/mycp/.m2/repository/com/test/te/testjar/1.1.6/testjar-1.1.6.jar
[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: driver}]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/mycp/workspace/TestProject/target/driver.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 28 17:27:10 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 129M/888M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- Why the 2nd jar (driver.jar) is not versioned (driver-1.1.6.jar) ?
- Why the 2nd jar not installed in local repo?

How to do this?

My requirement is create two jars **testjar-${project.version}.jar driver-${project.version}.jar** and install those two in two different artifact

/home/mycp/.m2/repossitory/com/test/te/**testjar**/${project-version}/**testjar-${project.version}.jar**

/home/mycp/.m2/repossitory/com/test/te/**driver**/${project-version}/**driver-${project.version}.jar**

Comment: The POM you are having is very wrong. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I need to create two jars from a single project. Both should be versioned and pushed to local repo.

Comment: Simply saying, from this project I need to create testjar-1.1.6.jar and driver-1.1.6.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the 2nd jar (driver.jar) is not versioned (driver-1.1.6.jar) ?

That is because you explicitely told the `maven-jar-plugin` that its name should be `driver` with `<finalName>driver</finalName>`. If you want to the version to be appended, you will need to have the following configuration: `<finalName>driver-${project.version}</finalName>`.

> Why the 2nd jar not installed in local repo?

That is because you have specified a phase of `<phase>install</phase>`, so it will executed after the `default-install` execution, which is the execution that installs artefact to the local repository. Instead, you should bind that execution to the `package` phase.

---

This is the configuration you should have for the `maven-jar-plugin`. A classifier is needed to create another jar.

```xml
<execution>
  <id>drive</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>jar</goal>
  </goals>
  <phase>package</phase>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>driver-${project.version}</finalName>
    <classifier>classifier</classifier>
    <includes>
      <include>com/test/te/p1/*.java</include>
      <include>com/test/te/p1/*.class</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

As a side note, I noticed that you also configured a `<resources>` element in your POM including Java and conf files. **You should not have that**. More specifically: all the resources should be placed under `src/main/resources` and all Java files under `src/main/java`. Then there is no need for that configuration.

---

Following from the comments, if you can't add a classifier, then you have to drop `maven-jar-plugin` and use [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) instead. This is a simple assembly descriptor that will get you started. Place this file under `src/main/assembly/assembly.xml`.

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>driver</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpackOptions>
                <includes>
                    <include>com/test/te/p1/*.class</include>
                </includes>
            </unpackOptions>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

with the following configuration in the POM:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor> <!-- point to the location of the assembly.xml file in your project structure -->
        </descriptors>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <finalName>driver-${project.version}</finalName>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: And if I am removing resources tag, then how can I add *.java files in jar.

Comment: @Surendhar `.java` files are not supposed to be in the jar. Only compiled classes go there. If you want to package the app sources, that is another matter.

Comment: That was really helped. Still I have two more issues. One is package hierarchy. Inside driver jar, there is a folder named driver which has the com folder but I want com folder sibling to META-INF. 2nd issue is, it is not installing the jar to local artifactory.

Comment: Fixed the first issue. any solution for 2nd issue?

Comment: @Surendhar No, if the new jar is correctly installed in local repository and not in artifactory, I think you should create another question will all the revelant information.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tunaki... :) Your answer really helped a lot.